# can not import inbuilt java class file (javax.naming.ldap.SortControl)

Tags: java, eclipse, ldap, jndi

I have downloaded [Openfire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/) sources and started to run it on Eclipse. I got a error saying `javax.naming.ldap.SortControl` class is not there, as illustrated on the following image:

[image]
 .

Since it is inbuilt Java class , what can i do to solve this problem. Full source has about 5 error messages, all of them are saying the same.

Comment: Aren't you using a JDK 1.5 or higher?

Answer (score 1):

There is some issue with your JRE. [SortControl should be in the JRE 5](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/naming/ldap/SortControl.html).

Answer (score 0):

Is your Eclipse project set up for the correct Java version?  As Thomas Jung points out, [`javax.naming.ldap.SortControl`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/naming/ldap/SortControl.html) first appeared in Java 5 / 1.5.  If a project is configured to use Java 1.4 or below, you'll get the error you're currently getting.

[`javax.naming.ldap.Control`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/naming/ldap/Control.html) is present in 1.3 and newer, and isn't erroring, so it definitely sounds like the project/JRE version is wrong.